# Is it possible to link a function to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, cordova, phonegap-build

So I'm building a chatbot, and I've taken an open source code online and wanting to modified the chat scripts by myself. The source code's script is built with new arrays, below are some examples of the scripts:

```
var convpatterns = new Array (
new Array (".*hello.*","Hello there! How are you?","Greetings!","Hi How are you?","Good day! "),
new Array ("I need (.*)" , "Why do you need $1?", "Would it really help you to get $1?" , "Are you sure you need $1?"),
new Array ("I remember (.*)", "Do you often think of $1?", "What else do you recollect?", "What in the present situation reminds you of $1?", "What else does $1 remind you of?"),
```

So for example, if the user typed "Hello", the chatbot will randomly select one of the replies from that array. What I was wondering is that if it's possible to link the user input from the different arrays into different functions. So like if the user typed "I need a friend", instead of choosing a random reply from the ones listed above, it will link to a function, eg Need() function, where I can add more options like the IF and ELSE rules.

The functions that generates the conversation:

```
function mainroutine() {
    uinput = document.mainscreen.BasicTextArea4.value;
    dialog = dialog + "User: " + uinput +  '\r' + "\n";
    conversationpatterns();
    dialog = dialog  +  '\r' + "\n";
    updatescreen();
}

function conversationpatterns() {
    for (i=0; i < convpatterns.length; i++) {
        re = new RegExp (convpatterns[i][0], "i");
        if (re.test(uinput)) {
            len = convpatterns[i].length - 1;
            index = Math.ceil( len * Math.random());
            reply = convpatterns[i][index];
            soutput = uinput.replace(re, reply);
            soutput = initialCap(soutput);
            dialog = dialog + "Avatar: " + soutput +  '\r' + "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
reply = convpatterns[i][index];
if (typeof reply === "function") reply = reply();
```

Now you can have

```
 function need() { ...; return someString; }
 ...
 ".*hello.*",need, "Hello there! How are you?"
```

or

```
 ".*hello.*",function() { ...; return someString }, "Hello there! How are you?"
```

Like this:

```js
var convpatterns = [
  [".*hello.*", function(str) { return str.toUpperCase()+"?" }, "Hello there! How are you?", "Greetings!", "Hi How are you?", "Good day! "],
  ["I need (.*)", "Why do you need $1?", "Would it really help you to get $1?", "Are you sure you need $1?"],
  ["I remember (.*)", "Do you often think of $1?", "What else do you recollect?", "What in the present situation reminds you of $1?", "What else does $1 remind you of?"]
];

function updatescreen() {
  document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=dialog;
}
function initialCap(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1);
}
var dialog="";

function mainroutine() {
  uinput = document.getElementById("BasicTextArea4").value;
  dialog = dialog + "User: " + uinput + '\r' + "\n";
  conversationpatterns();
  dialog = dialog + '\r' + "\n";
  updatescreen();
}

function conversationpatterns() {
  for (i = 0; i < convpatterns.length; i++) {
    re = new RegExp(convpatterns[i][0], "i");
    if (re.test(uinput)) {
      len = convpatterns[i].length - 1;
      index = Math.ceil(len * Math.random());
      reply = convpatterns[i][index];
      if (typeof reply === "function") reply = reply(uinput);
      soutput = uinput.replace(re, reply);
      soutput = initialCap(soutput);
      dialog = dialog + "Avatar: " + soutput + '\r' + "\n";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

```html
<textarea id="BasicTextArea4"></textarea><button type="button" onclick="mainroutine()">Talk</button>
<div id="update" class="pre"></div>
```

Comment: I mean how can I link the function Need() to the new array I created. So something like new Array (".*hello.*", Need())

Comment: See update. Just test if it is a string or a function

Comment: thanks! the updated answer is what I needed. I used: `new Array (".*hello.*",Hello)`. It links to the function Hello(), however do you know why does the soutput textarea keeps showing the word "undefined" when I submit the form? the Hello() function executes but then the "undefined" is always showing in the textarea.

Comment: Ooh, you wanted to add functions as possible options in the array. Then this answer should work. Maybe `Hello` isn't `return`-ing a string?